# Reading off the end of an array: running in terminal vs. debugger

Tags: c++, arrays, terminal

I encountered an error in my code where an if() statement was checking a value off the end of an array. IE,

```
int arrayX [2];
if(arrayX [2])
    FunctionCall();
```

This was leading to a function call that, for reasons related to the length of the above array, tried to subscript a vector with an out-of-bounds index, casuing the error. However, the error only occurred when running under the Xcode debugger; whenever I ran under terminal it didn't happen. This leads me to suspect that when I run under terminal, memory outside the array is being zeroed or tends to be zero for some other reason. The if statement gets tested for 80 different 'faulty' arrays per cycle so it seems unlikely that its a coincidence that it never pops up under terminal.

Just to be clear, my question is: why would unallocated or unrelated memory hold zeroes when run under terminal but not when run under a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many debuggers fill unused memory with some distinct pattern, so that exactly the behaviour you describe happens.

Comment: @Philip Ah, that sounds like it could be it. But doesn't it seem unlikely that all of the unused memory would be 0s under terminal?

Comment: @Matt: No it is very **likely** that the memory is cleared, so that your program cannot read data from a previous program. Anyway, accessing outside of an array is undefined, so anything can happen.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Oh ok. What does the clearing, the OS? Also, I don't see how **anything** can happen. An if() statement allows only two possible actions, and its argument is either zero or not-zero.

Comment: Actually, yes, the C-standard allows anything to happen. Your assumption that if is an choice between two alternatives is not valid in the presence of undefined code.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, the clearing is a security feature of most OS's. What if the previous program decoded passwords for another user?  :-)  **Anything** can happen, because the language standard says so. You only have arrayX[0] and arrayX[1], so what is arrayX[2]. There isn't one! Reading or writing a random memory address could be the location of your hard disk controller and trigger a format of your drive. (But your OS hopefully protects that address :-).

Comment: @Bo Persson: But within the limited context i'm talking about, since there is no data being written (only reading), doesn't that limit behavior to just two possibilities.

Comment: @Phil do you mean undefined code because I didn't show what FunctionCall(); does, or because there's more than one thing that could result from the if() statement, IE 1)do FunctionCall(), 2)skip FunctionCall(), or 3...N)unknown action. And if the latter, what could the alternative action be?

Comment: @Matt:  :-) **If** you succeed in reading a value, and you are converting it to bool, the result will be either true or false. Yes.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Cool. Is it possible to fail at reading a value from memory? Or just possible that you fail to reach that point in the code?

Comment: The C-Standard basically allows the compiler to generate whatever code it likes for an access to a non-existing array-member. Of course all compilers emit sane code for this, but the do not have to! Some versions of gcc started tetris on some special errors...

Comment: @Phil: Wow. I didn't know that. Although in this case the compiler used was a common factor under both cases, so I don't think it could have led to the difference, at least not on its own.

Comment: No, as I said, the difference is most likely the guard-values put by the debugger into memory locations your program is not supposed to read or write to detect just *this* mistake. The point about undefined behaviour is very minor.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the question?
Whatever the question, the answer is likely... The program generator can do that if it wants to. The behavior of the sample code is undefined so the resulting program's behavior is wholly unpredictable.

Comment: what is the program generator? Why is the sample code's behavior undefined? because the value at arrayX[2] is unknown?

Comment: @Matt: He means the compiler generating the executable. The value of arrayX[2] isn't just unknown, there **is** no arrayX[2]!

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell what data is outside the array. Shall there be any debugger that zeroes that part of memory, it may be the Xcode debugger, not the terminal. So it's very strange for me that you had no problems in terminal!!
You said "The if statement gets tested for 80 different 'faulty' arrays per cycle ", consider this: are you sure those "different" faulty arrays reside on "different" areas of ram actually (If it's static data compiler may put it in once place of ram and re-use it)? And, the compiler ( / interpreter) may optimize your code and also take care of memory.

Comment: yes, those arrays really do reside on different areas of ram, because they are different arrays, and not the same array 80 times in a row. I don't see what the compiler would have to do with it since the same compiler (and therefore executable) was used in each case.